# WPF ContextMenu of RowDefinition doesn't shown

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

```
var gridRow = new RowDefinition();
gridRow.Height = GridLength.Auto; 

var context = new ContextMenu();
context.Items.Add("Remove");  

gridRow.ContextMenu = context;
mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
```

This not opened ContextMenu when I right-clicked on row, but this works

```
this.mainGrid.ContextMenu = context;
```

So how to make work it on row ?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot add context menu directly to gridrow.

Comment: The clue is in the name `RowDefinition` you are adding a context menu to a definition, definitions are used to build controls they don't appear on them

Answer (score 0):

A row based context menu is not allowed as you have found. Best to provide a context menu based on the grid with commanding used such as

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Name="myGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyItem}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteItem}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Where the command is setup like this:

```
VM.DeleteItem 
     = new OperationCommand((o) => MessageBox.Show("Delete Me"),
                            (o) => (myGrid.SelectedItem as Order)?.InProgress == false );
```

[image]

Comment: I am drawing my grid dynamically no bindings, I am trying to access current index from base context but didn't  achieve that , is there any way?

Comment: @AlexandrSargsyan Your scenario confuses me, anything one can do in XAML, one can do in code behind and visa versa. One just recreates the process in code behind. So build off of the call `this.mainGrid.ContextMenu = context;` which is apparently the correct way of doing things. :-)

Comment: yes I know the principe of working GUI applications)) my question is other I can't get current index from grid context menu

Comment: @AlexandrSargsyan "Get the current index" Make the grid globally accessible and get the selected index. I show it in my example actually where I get the current selected item of the grid. It is the same principle.